# Code signing Thawte problems (Netbeans or Samsung Jet S8003)

Tags: netbeans, mobile-phones, certificate, midp

I recently bought a code signing certificate and have had successfully signed standalone java applet jar files with it.

I also have partial success signing java midlets.

But I can not get the Netbeans emulator (tried 6.9 and 7.0) or a samsung jet S8003 to recognize the certificate.

Netbeans Error

```
Reason: The content provider certificate issuer C=ZA;ST=Western Cape;L=Cape Town;O=Thawte Consulting cc;OU=Certification Services Division;CN=Thawte Premium Server CA;EmailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com is unknown
```

Samsung jet Error

```
Certificate error
```

Is there maybe a root certificate that i should install on these systems?
(BTW, successful on Samsung Chat 335 and numerous other Nokia phones)

Thanks

Comment: Any response will be welcome, I still can not even get Netbeans to recognized the certificate. I had partial with the Samsung SDK, as I was able to sign, deploy and installed it via OTA. Come on SO I have 50 of my hard earned points on the line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung SDK 1.2.2 came to my rescue to a very limited extent.
because I managed to find the exact root certificate my Thawte certificate chains to:
Namely

Owner: C=ZA;ST=Western Cape;L=Cape Town;O=Thawte Consulting cc;OU=Certification Services Division;CN=Thawte Premium Server CA;EmailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 03:00:00 EEST 1996 to Fri Jan 01 01:59:59 EET 2021
  Security Domain: identified_third_party
  State: enabled

The other certificates in  Samsung SDK 1.2.2 does not matter at all.

The neat thing about the Samsung SDK is that has a much broader range of root certificates.
Something that Netbeans does not have.

As for the Samsung jet issue, I am still battling that one, been active on the samsung development forum has brought no resolution yet.
Interestingly the Samsung s8003 has 2 root Thawte certs installed one very similar to the above.